# Windows Forms or XNA Studio

Tags: c#, winforms, xna

As the title says, is it a bad idea for making a game in Windows Forms than XNA Studio instead?

If you wanted to make a game (with a team (designer, sound composer and you as the programmer)), what do you choose for making a game? XNA or Windows Forms alone, if you wanted to make a game with C# programming language.

Your answer greatly will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Neither. Windows Forms is old (It's WPF now) and not meant for games _at all_. XNA, well, XNA is dead. It's not supported anymore and you have to almost hack it into newer VS versions (2012 and up). MonoGame is the only current solution, it's an open source version of XNA, but personally I don't like it.

Comment: Then, what do you choose for the helper (like WPF or XNA or Mono Game) if you and your team wanted to make a game in c#?
And why you choose it? Thank you

Comment: As I said, Forms are not meant to host games and XNA is dead. The only viable choice here is MonoGame.

Comment: Is the MonoGame is developed by Microsoft as well?

Comment: No, as I said it's an open source version of XNA.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with Monogame if you want to make a game in c#
It's not that hard and I personally had a fun time learning it.
As people already said XNA is kind of dead but I'm still using it, just because it's fun.
(this is just my opinion, it's your choice what you want to do ofcourse :) )

Monogame:
http://monogame.net/

Answer (score 1):

Windows Forms are not designed for game development. While it is possible, it is not recommended.

XNA Game Studio draws a window, sets up a game loop, and gives you a Draw() and Update() methods all for you.

Answer (score 0):

Unity3D or UDK - that's the way to go.

Windows Forms and WPF are definitely not designed for game development, and as for XNA - not sure if it's really dead, but Microsoft are notorious for killing their own technologies every few years, so I wouldn't be surprised.

So the answer is:

http://unity3d.com/

http://www.unrealengine.com/udk/

Comment: Regarding XNA: http://www.gamasutra.com/view/news/185894/Its_official_XNA_is_dead.php

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend SFML for .net It's not hard to get going animating things, and getting the sound effects and stuff going. It's not UDK, but it's really good.

(I wrote sdl, meant SFML, sorry!)

[SFML .NET Download](http://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml.net/)